# Export job schedule in cogons

Tags: cognos

I have a question concerning jobs in the scheduler. I created a job on the test server that executes 8 reports that get emailed with a message.  I would like it to go to production.  Is there a way to export and import that job ?

Answer (score 0):

Administration -> Configuration -> New Export -> (Select Folder that contains job)

This export will include Jobs.